# HTML extra cell at bottom right side of a table for displaying a total

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div with a background. I would like to add a cell with the sum of all values in a column, pasted as an extra cell to the bottom of the table at the right side (the right column is the column with numbers). This should happen without my preceding column cells removing my background. For clarity I have added a picture of an example template.

[image]

Now my question is, does there exist a HTML predefined tag or option to add just one cell at the right of a row, or would I have to style a preceding td tag with colspan=3 with transparent background, no borders etc... to get this result.

Comment: How about setting background transparent to preceding cells?

Comment: "or would I have to style a preceding td tag with colspan=3 with transparent background, no borders etc..."

Comment: Ups, I don't know how could I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is no. There is no way to create a table that is not a perfect rectangle. But you can, as other have pointed out, style a table to get your desired look.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a colspan=3 and text-align right for the cells

Comment: I already stated in the question that I knew of this solution, but wondered whether a better solution existed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined HTML tag for your purpose. Your mentioned solution is the best choice.